# Subordinate charm defines a binding, container won't select it

Tags: networking, juju, openstack

I'm testing an openstack environment using OVN; my ovn-chassis charms use a separate space binding for "data", separating tunnel traffic.
When adding octavia to the solution running into containers, I haven't found a way to create a bundle / overlay definition that would spawn the container in the correct manner. By hand, I am able to get a functioning deployment creating the container by hand:

```
juju deploy octavia -n 0 --bind infrastructure
juju deploy ovn-chassis --bind infrastructure
juju integrate octavia ovn-chassis
juju add-machine lxd:0 --constraints spaces=infrastructure,tunnel 
created container 0/lxd/12
juju add-unit octavia --to 0/lxd/12
```

I wonder if there is a way to write the bundle to do the extra binding.

Comment: **Welcome the Ask Ubuntu community.** To help community members better understand and resolve your issue, please edit your question to include the version of the Ubuntu OS that you're using. Thanks